I can't use LEVENSHTEIN function in spring
I wanted to search posts similar to 80% of their title, here is full code:
@Override
public Page<Post> findPosts(Pageable pageable, Post.Status status, String category, String tag, String keyword) {
    String jpql = "SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.status = :status";
    String countJpql = "SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Post p WHERE p.status = :status";
    Category category1 = null;
    Tag tag1 = null;

    if(keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
        jpql += " AND (1 - (LEVENSHTEIN(LOWER(p.title), LOWER(:keyword)) / GREATEST(CHAR_LENGTH(p.title), CHAR_LENGTH(:keyword)))) >= 0.8";
        countJpql += " AND (1 - (LEVENSHTEIN(LOWER(p.title), LOWER(:keyword)) / GREATEST(CHAR_LENGTH(p.title), CHAR_LENGTH(:keyword)))) >= 0.8";
    }

    if (category != null && !category.isEmpty()) {
        TypedQuery<Category> categoryTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.title = :category", Category.class);
        categoryTypedQuery.setParameter("category", category);
        category1 = categoryTypedQuery.getSingleResult();
        jpql += " AND :category1 MEMBER OF p.categories";
        countJpql += " AND :category1 MEMBER OF p.categories";
    }

    if (tag != null && !tag.isEmpty()) {
        TypedQuery<Tag> tagTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Tag c WHERE c.title = :tag", Tag.class);
        tagTypedQuery.setParameter("tag", tag);
        tag1 = tagTypedQuery.getSingleResult();
        jpql += " AND :tag1 MEMBER OF p.tags";
        countJpql += " AND :tag1 MEMBER OF p.tags";
    }




    if (pageable.getSort().isSorted()) {
        jpql += " ORDER BY ";
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
        pageable.getSort().forEach(order ->
                joiner.add("p." + order.getProperty() + " " + order.getDirection().name())
        );
        jpql += joiner.toString();
    }

    TypedQuery<Post> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, Post.class);
    query.setParameter("status", status);
    query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
    query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

    TypedQuery<Long> countQuery = entityManager.createQuery(countJpql, Long.class);
    countQuery.setParameter("status", status);

    if (category1 != null) {
        query.setParameter("category1", category1);
        countQuery.setParameter("category1", category1);
    }
    if (tag1 != null) {
        query.setParameter("tag1", tag1);
        countQuery.setParameter("tag1", tag1);
    }
    if(keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
        query.setParameter("keyword", keyword.toLowerCase());
        countQuery.setParameter("keyword", keyword.toLowerCase());
    }

    List<Post> posts = query.getResultList();
    long total = countQuery.getSingleResult();

    return new PageImpl<>(posts, pageable, total);
}

in this part i used levenshtein function ,main part is here:
if(keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
    jpql += " AND (1 - (LEVENSHTEIN(LOWER(p.title), LOWER(:keyword)) / GREATEST(CHAR_LENGTH(p.title), CHAR_LENGTH(:keyword)))) >= 0.8";
    countJpql += " AND (1 - (LEVENSHTEIN(LOWER(p.title), LOWER(:keyword)) / GREATEST(CHAR_LENGTH(p.title), CHAR_LENGTH(:keyword)))) >= 0.8";
}

this code throws this error: Parameter 1 of function 'greatest()' has type 'COMPARABLE', but argument is of type 'java.lang.Object' mapped to '2000'
here is the LEVENSHTEIN sql query:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN(s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);

    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1);
    SET s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2);
    SET cv1 = 0x00;
    SET j = 1;
    WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j)));
        SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET i = 1;
    WHILE i <= s1_len DO
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1);
        SET c = i;
        SET cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i));
        SET j = 1;
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
            SET c_temp = c + 1;
            SET c = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + (s1_char != SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1));
            IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
            IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c)));
            SET j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET cv1 = cv0;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN c;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

